# In Dart: sort a part of a list in-place

Tags: dart

Is there a function in the Dart standard library with which it is possible to sort a part of a list from a given start index to an end index in-place (without copying that part)? I am searching for something like the [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-int-int-)  method in Java. (The [sort method of lists in Dart](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.1/dart-core/List/sort.html) sorts the complete list and the [sublist method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.1/dart-core/List/sublist.html) creates a new list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method I know if in the core libraries. You could write it as:

```
/// Sorts [list] between [start] (inclusive) and [end] (exclusive).
void sortSublist<T>(List<T> list, int start, int end) {
  list.setRange(start, end, list.sublist(start, end)..sort());
}
```

Comment: thanks and +1, but this would copy the sub-list, I am searching for something that works in-place

Comment: I'm not aware of any - you may need to write your own if you want an in place sort.